# div will not stay at the bottom of the browser

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I'm trying to get the #footer div to stay at the bottom of the #content div **and** the #sidebar div, but what once worked elsewhere, doesn't seem to want to work anymore and I'm at a loss.

Works here: http://wiki.tf-575.com/index.php?title=RBL_Store
But not here: http://beta.tf-575.com/index.php?title=RBL_Store

```css
body {
  background: #020B12;
  font: x-small sans-serif;
  color: B3DFFC;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  background: #020B12 url(background-tile.png) top left repeat-y;
  font: normal;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#header {
  background: #020B12;
  color: B3DFFC;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 67px;
}

#sidebar {
  background: none;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 84px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  width: 164px;
  top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
}

#content {
  color: #446C90;
  margin-top: -48px;
  min-width: 960px;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 165px;
}

#footer {
  background: url("footer.png") no-repeat scroll left bottom transparent;
  clear: both;
  color: #446C90;
  font-size: 90%;
  min-height: 82px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 82px 0 0 165px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <snip />
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <snip />
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <snip />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <snip />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that on the beta site the sidebar is positioned absolute, so the float is ignored and the

```
clear:both;
```

doesn't push down the footer anymore

Answer (score 0):

try setting the width of the footer to 100%

Comment: Tried that just before I'd posted and it didn't seem to have an effect.